# jQuery Flot with multi yaxis and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Need help to set options for multiple y axes in Flot. This is the current graph: [image]

I want to apply these properties to the y axes:

```js
$.plot("#placeholder", data, {
        xaxis: {
          tickDecimals: 0
        },
        yaxis: [{
          position: "left",
          min: 0,
          tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
            return val + "v";
          },
        },{
          min: 0,
          position: "right",
          tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
            return val + "M";
          },
        }]
});
```

But I do not understand why my code does not work here: [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TS111/ofv6fb2t/)

Comment: i guess you just copy paste the documentation code and compare yours with that , i have copied from documentation http://jsfiddle.net/ofv6fb2t/2/

Comment: I want two y axes. One axis to the left (position: "left",) with values ("483994v"  "479060v" ...) of datasets objects: "usa", "russia", "uk". The second to the right (position: "right") with values ("55627M" "55475M"...) of datasets objects: "germany".

Comment: then i guess you need to check Multiple Axis example
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-multiple/index.html

Comment: I know this, but it doesn`t work with chackbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for multiple axes is `yaxes` instead of `yaxis`. See this update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofv6fb2t/4/) and the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#multiple-axes).

[image]